# is it possible to run a rollup plugin without an input file (in a multi bundle instance)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, plugins, bundle, rollup

I have a situation where I am bundling multiple files via rollup `cli` an [example](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#configuration-files) of this is available in documentation.

I export an array of bundles like so:

```js
export default [
    {
        input: 'packages/A/index.js',
        output: {
            name: '[name]Bundle',
            file: '[name].umd.js',
            format: 'umd'
        }
    },
    {
        input: 'packages/B/index.js',
        output: {
            name: '[name]Bundle',
            file: '[name].umd.js',
            format: 'umd'
        }
    }
];
```

And then I have a function that adds a common config to each bundle (think plugins) so something like:

```js
import path from "path";

import alias from '@rollup/plugin-alias';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';


const augment = configs => {

    const generateAlias = (symbol, location) => {
        return {
            find: symbol,
            replacement: path.resolve(process.cwd(), location)
        };
    }

    const entries = [
        generateAlias("@", "src/"),
        generateAlias("~", "src/assets/scss/"),
        generateAlias("#", "src/assets/img/"),
        generateAlias("%", "config/"),
    ];

    const plugins = [
        alias({
            entries
        }),
        resolve({ browser: true }),
    ];

    return configs.map(entry => {
        return {
            ...entry,
            plugins
        }
    });
}

export {
    augment
}
```

And the I wrap the above exported array in `augment` like:

```js
const bundles = [/* above example */];

export default augment(bundles);
```

Now this all works fine, but I have two plugins that I don't actually want to apply to each bundle I just want to run them once all the bundles have built, those two plugins are; [rollup-plugin-serve](https://github.com/thgh/rollup-plugin-serve) and [rollup-plugin-workbox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-workbox) now neither of these actually have anything to do with any of the files being bundled, and make no sense to instantiate more than once.

What I would like to do as part of the `augment` function to to append them to the end of the returned array something like:

```js
const exportedArray = configs.map(/* function from above */);

exportedArray.push(...[
        {
                plugins: [
                        serve({
                                host,
                                port,
                                contentBase: 'dist/'
                        })
                ]
        }
]);

return exportedArray;
```

And this would not contain an `input`, I have tried the above and rollup complains, the alternative option would be to add these plugins to the final bundle on the array, I just prefer the idea of instantiating them without them being tied to a particular bundle.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

Rollup needs an input file to work, but that doesn't mean you cannot simply throw away the result of the file. You can make an empty file `empty.js` (or maybe add some comment in it) and use that as the input. Just leave out the *output* properties so that the result is not written anywhere.

---EDIT---

a bit like this:

```
export default {
    input: './empty.js',
    plugins: [{
        name: 'test plugin',
        load() {
            console.log('test plugin')
        }
    }]
}
```

---EDIT---

Alternatively you can write to a dummy file and remove it again

```js
const fs = require('fs')

export default {
    input: './empty.js',
    output: {
        file: './dummy',
    },
    plugins: [{
        name: 'test plugin',
        writeBundle(options) {
            fs.unlinkSync(options.file)
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: `output` is required.

Comment: no it doesn't, the code I just added as an example works fine

Comment: It's in the doc http://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#configuration-files

Comment: I know it's in the docs, but it works without, if you really want to you can also just dump it to a dummy file

Comment: It fails with `[!] Error: You must specify "output.file" or "output.dir" for the build.` I think you're using an older version.

Comment: 2.7.6 (latest) very strange

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem in our own rollup plugin. We use rollup to generate many bundles from many inputs.  However, since the build takes a long time, we determine which inputs need to be built and which is unchanged. So there may be a situation where the rollup runs without any input.

The only solution is to create an empty file, which will not be written to disk as a result.

Config has no any input:

```js
const rollupOptions: rollup.RollupOptions = {
    output: {
        dir: 'some-dir',
    },
    plugins: [buildManager(entryFiles)],
}
```

Plugin `buildManager` creates inputs on `buildStart` hook:

```js
export function buildManager(entryFiles: string[]): rollup.Plugin {
    const emptyRunId = 'no-input-for-this-run';

    return {
        name: 'build-manager',
        buildStart() {
            for (const entryFile of entryFiles) {
                // if some condition met, emit chunk (~ create an input)
            }

            // if the condition does not met even once, no chunk is created, but rollup needs at least one input
            this.emitFile({
                id: emptyRunId,
                fileName: emptyRunId,
                type: 'chunk',
            });
        },
        resolveId(source) {
            if (source === emptyRunId) {
                // The leading \0 instructs other plugins and rollup not to try to resolve, load or transform this module
                return `\0${emptyRunId}`;
            }
            return null;
        },
        load(id) {
            if (id.includes(emptyRunId)) {
                // some random code to avoid rollup empty chunk warning
                return 'export const empty = true;';
            }

            return null;
        },
        generateBundle(options, bundle) {
            // remove empty chunk from final bundle to not write that file
            if (bundle[emptyRunId]) {
                delete bundle[emptyRunId];
            }
        },
    };
}
```

So it could be easily used as standalone plugin to handle empty run.